# sessions should be closed in hibernate when we use c3p0 connection pooling?

Tags: java, hibernate, session, c3p0

I'm wondering whether we should use `session.close()` when I use c3p0 connection pooling in hibernate? or c3p0 automatically closes after certain time interval? Do I need to just open the session by

```
SessionFactory factory = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory();
Session session=factory.openSession();
```

Because in the following tutorial it doesn't close the session.

http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/enterprise-java/hibernate/hibernate-connection-pool-configuration-with-c3p0-example/

What's the correct way?

Edit:

This would be my code

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
@Override
public JSONObject  getUserDetails(int id) {
    long lStartTime = new Date().getTime(); 
    JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
    try(Session session=factory.openSession()) {
        Employee emp=(Employee)session.load(Employee.class,id);     

        if(emp != null) {
            obj.put("id", emp.getId());
            obj.put("name", emp.getName());
        }                  
        long lEndTime = new Date().getTime();
        log.info("[ Personal Details ]Time elapsed For Fetching :"+(lEndTime - lStartTime));

    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would recommend that you `close` your resources as soon as you can, that way the connection will be returned to the pool *faster*. You can also use the [`try-with-resources` Statement](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) to make sure that happens.

```
SessionFactory factory = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory();
try (Session session = factory.openSession()) {
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks Elliott. But, my question is should I write "session.close()" explicitly in the code?

Comment: If you don't use a `try-with-resources`, then **yes** you should *explicitly* write `session,close()` in a *`finally`* block.

Comment: Thanks for your update. But what exactly makes the diff?

Comment: try-with-resources will automatically closes the session?

Comment: I've updated my question with the code. Can you please check it whether its the right way?

Comment: *The `try-with-resources` statement ensures that each resource is closed at the end of the statement.*

Comment: Your updated code looks fine (but you shouldn't swallow `Exception`; at least `print` or log it), but you should indicate that it was an *edit* to your question after the fact.

Comment: It was a just for showing purpose. Definetely I'd be using logs in catch. Thanks for your info.

Answer (score 0):

As ELLIOT said its better to close sessions manually without relying on any thing or you can use the try block specified above  if you are using java 7 or above.

Answer (score 0):

Yes using try-with-resources is an better option.

But here are few postulates about it:

1. Any exception thrown from try-with-resources statements are
   suppressed.
2. You can use catch, finally block as with normal
   try-catch.
3. You can declare multiple resources separated by semi-colon inside the try-with-resources like

> ```
> try (
>         java.util.zip.ZipFile zf =
>              new java.util.zip.ZipFile(zipFileName);
>         java.io.BufferedWriter writer = 
>             java.nio.file.Files.newBufferedWriter(outputFilePath, charset)
>     )
> ```

4. It closes the resources after ending of try block first i.e. if any exception comes from try block or not. After that it executes catch, finally block.
5. Your resource which is declared inside try-with-resource statement must implement the AutoCloseable or Closeable Interface.